# Conexão ao banco de dados lenta

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tenho um programa em C# que quando o inicio e peço para me mostrar os dados inseridos no Sql Server demora a abrir, mas depois dessa vez já é mais rápido. Existe forma da primeira vez ser mais rápida?

A minha conexão é feita desta forma e só uso stored procedure:

```
public class AcessoBaseDadosSqlServer
{
    private SqlConnection conexao()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.StringConnection);
    }

    private SqlParameterCollection sqlParameterCollection = new SqlCommand().Parameters;

    public void LimparParametros()
    {
        sqlParameterCollection.Clear();
    }

    public void AdicionarParametros(string nomeParametro, object valorParametro)
    {
        sqlParameterCollection.Add(new SqlParameter(nomeParametro, valorParametro));
    }


    // INSERIR, ALTERAR E APAGAR
    public object ExecutarManipulacao(CommandType commandType, string nomeStoredProcedureOuTextoSQL)
    {
        try
        {
            // criar um ligação à base de dados
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = conexao();
            // abrir ligação
            sqlConnection.Open();
            //criar um comando
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            sqlCommand.CommandType = commandType;
            sqlCommand.CommandText = nomeStoredProcedureOuTextoSQL;
            sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 7200;

            foreach (SqlParameter SqlParameter in sqlParameterCollection)
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(SqlParameter.ParameterName, SqlParameter.Value));
            }

            return sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    // Consulta
    public DataTable ExecutarConsulta(CommandType commandType, string nomeStoredProcedureOuTextoSql)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = conexao();
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            sqlCommand.CommandType = commandType;
            sqlCommand.CommandText = nomeStoredProcedureOuTextoSql;
            sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 7200;

            foreach (SqlParameter sqlParameter in sqlParameterCollection)
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(sqlParameter.ParameterName, sqlParameter.Value));
            }

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

            return dataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exiba a conexão, como vamos dizer se pode ou não ser mais rápida se nem sabemos o que você está fazendo ?

Comment: @bigown a minha pergunta já está editada, mostro como faço a minha conexão, espero que assim já esteja um pouco mais clara. Cumprimentos

Comment: não entendi o porque desse foreach e o parameter collection estar na classe

Comment: @Bsalvo tem toda a razão, já editei e já mostrei como a conexão é feita, espero que esteja melhor.

Comment: nesse código tem dois dos erros mais cometidos na programação hoje em dia. Leia pelo menos as primeiras de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a101%20%5bexce%c3%a7%c3%a3o%5d. Não trate exceção se não sabe como fazer. Tem outras coisas no mínimo esquisitas no código. Reabri.

Comment: @bigown Obrigado, não sou experiente por isso acredito estar a cometer erros e práticas menos adequadas, por isso preciso de pessoas como você que me dê direcções para conseguir fazer as coisas da forma correcta e evoluir. Obrigado

Comment: @DiogoSousa quando é inexperiente é melhor aprender primeiro para depois pegar coisas mais complexas. O que você está fazendo é o que se chama fazer o telhado antes de construir o alicerce, não costuma dar certo. A minha sugestão é começar mais devagar, entendendo cada conceito antes de tentar fazer código funcionais.

Comment: Assim como @bigown falou, há coisas bem estranhas na forma que escolheu para acessar o banco de dados. Segue um link para começar do mais básico em acesso a um banco de dados SQL Server: http://www.macoratti.net/08/11/c_sql_m1.htm

Comment: obrigado @Perozzo pela dica, segui um tutorial e pensei que era a melhor forma, mas vou tentar descobrir formas mais corretas de fazer, mais uma vez obrigado.